# How do I put an application to run in the background when it's closed?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am creating an application on **Node.Js** using **Electron** and I need it to continue running in the background when it is closed and *becomes an application icon next to the computer's clock* for the user to have access to. But I did not find references to do this task, so the question is:

**How do I put an application to run in the background when it's closed?**

Comment: You could simply hide the browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is listen to the `close` event like this:

```
var tray;

mainWindow.on('close', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    mainWindow.hide();
    tray = new Tray('./path/to/icon.png');
});
```

This will instead of closing the window hide the window and make a tray icon.

But you probably want to open the window again if you double click the tray icon or something and for that you can do:

```
tray.on('double-click', function () {
    mainWindow.show();
    tray.destroy();
});
```

[Tray documentation](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/tray/)

[Close event](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#event-close)

Answer (score 0):

Try to start a [service](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) to do it.